# Разделить строку на две переменные

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вот допустим есть строка: 1960 12374
Как разделить строку на две переменные чтобы было
a = 1960
b = 12374

Comment: a,b = string.split()

Comment: `a, b = map(int, string.split())`

Answer (score 1):

Представим, что у вас есть строка. Её можно разделить методом `split()`, но в таком случае, у нас в переменных `a` и `b` останутся строки.

```
>>> my_str = '1860 12374'
>>> a,b = my_str.split()
>>> a
'1860'
>>> b
'12374'
```

Поэтому нам необходимо привести их сразу к целочисленному значению. Для этого мы воспользуемся функцией `map()`

```
>>> a, b = map(int, my_str.split())
>>> a
1860
>>> b
12374
```